# I Display a image On Web Brower in Windows Phone. I want to Open a Default Brower then I click on image

Tags: windows-phone-7

I create a windows phone 8 apps. It's working well. right now i am add a Ad in my windows phone apps using web Browser. I have a URL link. Using this link i have open a web Browser then i open web browser this browser display a GIF image. I wanna just then i click on this GIF image when the default browser of my device is lunch with another URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Handler for the Navigating event of the WebBrowser

and in the handler, check the URL to which it is navigating, if the navigating URL is what you want then redirect it to the Phone's browser using the WebBrowserTask

```
private void webBrowserControl_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Uri.ToString().StartsWith("somexyzurl"))
        {
            e.Cancel = true; // stop the navigation
            WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
            //set the task's URL here then show the task
            task.Show();
        }
     }
```

For this, you have to make your GIF as a hyperlink.

EDIT: Actually in the place of "somexyzurl" you have to place the link which you are using for the GIF URL.

Comment: Then i test my apps it execute webBrowserControl_Navigation method not display my apps webBrowser

Comment: Your apps webbrowser or phones default browser ?